# skipping null values when parsing json in android?

Tags: android, facebook, json

I am parsing json object from facebook. 
In my facebook json object, there are string keys inside key array "data".

My Code as follows,

```
"data": [
  {
     "id": "100001211447563_300696056647440",
     "from": {
        "name": "Seho Lee",
        "id": "100001211447563"
     },
     "story": "Seho Lee is now using Facebook in English (US).",
     "story_tags": {
        "0": [
           {
              "id": 100001211447563,
              "name": "Seho Lee",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 8
           }
        ]
     },
     "type": "status",
     "created_time": "2012-01-19T09:13:04+0000",
     "updated_time": "2012-01-19T09:13:04+0000",
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  },
  {
     "id": "100001211447563_298802933503419",
     "from": {
        "name": "Seho Lee",
        "id": "100001211447563"
     },
     "story": "Seho Lee started using Graph API Explorer.",
     "story_tags": {
        "23": [
           {
              "id": 145634995501895,
              "name": "Graph API Explorer",
              "offset": 23,
              "length": 18
           }
        ],
        "0": [
           {
              "id": 100001211447563,
              "name": "Seho Lee",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 8
           }
        ]
     },
     "picture": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v43/11/145634995501895/app_1_145634995501895_4870.gif",
     "link": "http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/",
     "caption": "A tool to help you browse objects within the Facebook Graph API, manage permissions, obtain access tokens and generally learn how it all works.",
     "actions": [
        {
           "name": "Comment",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100001211447563/posts/298802933503419"
        },
        {
           "name": "Like",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100001211447563/posts/298802933503419"
        }
     ],
     "type": "link",
     "created_time": "2012-01-16T09:47:57+0000",
     "updated_time": "2012-01-16T09:47:57+0000",
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  },
  {
     "id": "100001211447563_298789650171414",
     "from": {
        "name": "Seho Lee",
        "id": "100001211447563"
     },
     "story": "Seho Lee likes myFBCovers.com.",
     "story_tags": {
        "15": [
           {
              "id": 160901873998019,
              "name": "myFBCovers.com",
              "offset": 15,
              "length": 14
           }
        ],
        "0": [
           {
              "id": 100001211447563,
              "name": "Seho Lee",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 8
           }
        ]
     },
     "type": "status",
     "created_time": "2012-01-16T08:57:33+0000",
     "updated_time": "2012-01-16T08:57:33+0000",
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  }
```

when I parsing this json object, String key "likes" is sometimes exist and sometimes do not exist in "data" jsonArray. So when I parsing JsonString "likes", sometimes I gets `JSONException` since I am parsing null value. Is there any way to skipping "null" json value?

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: simple..... put try catch & catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this is to check key. since you mentioned key exists sometimes. did you mean the value?

use JSONObjects method has(key)

```
data = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonObjRecv.toString()).nextValue();
if data.has("like"){
...
}
```

to check whether the value is null check with isNull("name")

Comment: how to check in dis case **data:[{key:value},null,{key:value}]**

Answer (score 2):

if try catch it, next processes will be skipped.
you can check by isNull("name") method.